# MongoDB Tree Structure

Tags: json, mongodb, tree, parent-child

I have a Mongo collection with the following documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b09a97f630f3070ad0cabd"),
    "Parent" : "",
    "ID" : "123"
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b09a97f630f3070ad0cabe"),
    "Parent" : "123",
    "ID" : "098"
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b09a97f630f3070ad0caca"),
    "Parent" : "123",
    "ID" : "567"
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b09a97f630f3070ad0cabf"),
    "Parent" : "098",
    "ID" : "abc"
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b09a97f630f3070ad0cace"),
    "Parent" : "567",
    "ID" : "def"
}
```

I would like create a collection with the format:

```
{
    "ID" : 123,
    "children" : [ 
        {
            "ID" : "098",
            "childs" : [ 
                {
                    "ID" : "abc",
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "ID" : 567,
            "childs" : [ 
                {
                    "ID" : "def"
                }
             ]
         }
     ]
}
```

I am able to do the correct queries to find all the children of each parent but am unable to find a way to export the documents to a new collection in the tree format listed above. All help is appreciated!

Comment: why do you have two different ways to define children ? `children` and `childs`? How deep would your structure be? I would suggest to try map-reduce

Comment: @sidgate for now my tree structure is only 3 levels